# Collectl How to get timestamp per interval

Tags: timestamp, collect, subsystem, collectctl

I have created an export module that uses variables from the collectl/formatit.ph script. I am trying to get the collectl timestamp that's used during every interval cycle, for example the timestamps that are shown when passing "-oT" to collectl. What variable stores this timestamp and can it be used globally?

```
    ./collectl -oT
    waiting for 1 second sample...
    #         <--------CPU--------><----------Disks-----------><----------Network---------->
    #Time     cpu sys inter  ctxsw KBRead  Reads KBWrit Writes   KBIn  PktIn  KBOut  PktOut
    14:44:19    1   0  1171   1790      0      0     40      4      5     15      2      10
```

In this case I want the variable that contains the value "14:44:19". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the unix epoch timestamp in global variable $fullTime